# Channel of pointer that the pointer created by other goroutine

Tags: go

All my questions are written in code ...

I have no idea about if golang has heap memory and stack memory.

If a func has its own stack memory, does another func can read it ??!

the code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "strconv"
    "time"
)

type People struct {
    name string
    age int
}

func receiver(ch chan *People){
    for{
        // 2. Why the pointer a variable in receiver stack returned by <-ch can reach
        // the stack belongs to sender?
        fmt.Println((<-ch).name)
    }
}
func sender(ch chan *People){
    for{
        time.Sleep(3*time.Second)
        // 1. the People instance is created by sender and 
        // the pointer may points to the local stack in sender's call stack.
        ch <- &People{name: strconv.Itoa(rand.Int())}
    }
}
func main(){
    ch := make(chan *People, 10)
    go receiver(ch)
    go sender(ch)

    // join...
    time.Sleep(time.Hour)
}
```

Comment: When a value is declared in a function, it will live in stack memory; but if the value outlives the function (e.g. because it is returned, or passed on a channel), it "escapes" and is allocated on the heap instead.

Answer (score 1):

Go compiler does escape analysis to check whether an object should be on stack OR heap. The language specs doesn't make a distinction though, which means the compiler can take different course in future than exists today. By course I mean optimization and decision technique than one exists today not the genesis.

Check this [stack or heap](https://golang.org/doc/faq#stack_or_heap).

If you build the program with escape analysis flags:

`go build -gcflags="-m"`

You will notice that it shows:

```
(<-ch).name escapes to heap
...
 "&People literal escapes to heap"
```

So go compiler by virtue of escape analysis knows before hand what things **could** be on stack and what should be on heap.

=> so the things that you have doubt on are escaped to be on heap.